# Swift Convert Type Any Object to Type String

Tags: swift

Below is the code I am using, but the array returns null.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("admin1")
    
    databaseHandle = ref!.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.postData.append(snapshot.value as! String)
        
    })
```

Is there a way to convert a type any object to type string or display a type any object in a label?

Comment: You cannot _convert_ to string. If it _is_ a string, then `as! String` will cast it to a string. However, that probably has nothing to do with "the array returns nil". That's probably happening because your code is asynchronous. Or because your query returns no values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using admin1 child just call the whole database, return it as a dict then put admin1 as the key in your dictionary. This is how it should be done:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

databaseHandle = ref!.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
         self.postData.append(dict["admin1"] as! String)
    }
})
```

This is assuming your database looks like the following.
[image]

If your admin1 has a plus next to it then you have to use the same process as above but keeping admin1 as a child and then entering the key of whatever value you want.